# A right hexagon and right pyramid

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Does it possible to obtain a regular hexagon as a section of right pyramid with the base of the form of regular pentagon?

O.Ganyushkin

Comment: Do you mean "regular hexagon" and "regular pentagon"? A "right pyramid" makes sense but the other two don't.

Comment: The short answer is "no" - I don't have time to give the full answer - maybe in a week or two! You can, however obtain an irregular hexagon.